# Adding New Row To HTML Table

Tags: php, html

I just wanna ask how can I add a new row to an HTML table?

The first column should have a *select* tool and the second column should have a text box. Like there's a button below the table that when clicked, a new row will be added to the table. I really don't know how so perhaps can you give me a sample code? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you provide some more info?Do you need to use variable or is a plain html table?

Comment: what code? through javascript?

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>[whatever you need]</tr>
```

Of course, it would be better if you could describe your situation better.  Considering that 'PHP' tag is there.

Comment: Like there's a button below the table that when clicked, a new row will be added to the table.

Comment: A row of what?  A select box?  What was written in the select box?

Comment: @jeje_13: you need to use scripting language or framework  like js or jquery,etc

Comment: There's a lot of option in the select box. So I guess like "sample1" "sample2" could be part of the options.